# how to remove/hide wordpress menu from admin dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to hide wp menu from my admin dashboard..
how remove/hide wordpress menu from admin dashboard .. i was try many code seems not work
I want to hide wpchtmlp_page menu item s. How to remove wpchtmlp_page menu item in admin page?

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menu_items', 9999);
remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=wpchtmlp_page' );
```

[image]

Comment: what is the problem with the solution you provided?? And please reformat your code section...

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be adding an actual function to the [`admin_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_menu/) hook. With the code you provided, it looks like you're adding a (potentially non-existent?) function to the `admin_menu` hook, and calling `remove_menu_page` without being on a hook, so it's firing way before the page is actually added.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'so_59866103_remove_menu_items', 999 );
function so_59866103_remove_menu_items(){
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=wpchtmlp_page' );
}
```

Generally speaking, you can also use a hook that runs later and before rendering (such as [`admin_init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init)), which can be especially useful if that menu item was added in an unorthodox way.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'so_59866103_remove_menu_items', 999 );
function so_59866103_remove_menu_items(){
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=wpchtmlp_page' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove menu from admin dashboard. Also you can remove any submenu as well. follow the sample code

```
function remove_item_from_menu() {
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=elementor_library' ); // removes elementor addons , menu item added by plugins
    remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' ); // removes comment menu
    remove_submenu_page('themes.php', 'theme-editor.php'); // remove submenu called theme edititor inside appearance
    remove_submenu_page('themes.php', 'widgets.php'); // removes widgets submenu
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_item_from_menu' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function cyberscap_menu_section() {
    remove_menu_page('easy-wp-smtp');
    remove_menu_page('elementor');
    remove_menu_page('cyberscap-panel');
    remove_submenu_page('themes.php', 'themes.php');
}
add_action('admin_head', 'cyberscap_menu_section');
```

you can do this. (admin.php?page=**elementor**)

Update (in some case):

```
function remove_menus() {
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=elementor_library' );
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=cyberscap_footer' );
    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=cyberscap_mega_menu' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
```